# SQL Trigger can't detect my identity column

Tags: sql-server, triggers, insert, identity

I want to have this column HiddenID which I use as IDENTITY so that when my trigger updates a column, it will know which to update because currently it does not, so whenever I insert a new record, the trigger updates what its supposed to for all the columns with the value which is meant for the new record. But it returns me the error

> The multi-part identifier "inserted.HiddenId" could not be bound.

**Trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertNoOfDays ON CurrentApplication
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @temp INT
    SELECT @temp = (coalesce(DATEDIFF(day, StartDate, EndDate),0)+1) --Default 0
    FROM inserted

    UPDATE CurrentApplication SET NoOfDays = @temp WHERE CurrentApplication.HiddenID = inserted.HiddenId
END
```

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE CurrentApplication
(
StartDate       datetime        ,
EndDate         datetime        ,
NoOfDays        integer,
StaffID         integer         ,
AppStatus       varchar(30)     DEFAULT 'PENDING',
HiddenID        integer         IDENTITY
)
```

Comment: Why not just have a *computed column*? As it is, your trigger is broken because it assumes that `inserted` contains exactly *one* row. This is not, generally, the case. Triggers should be written to cope with `inserted` (and `deleted`) containing 0, 1, or *many* rows.

Comment: Indeed. Drop your column and use `ALTER TABLE CurrentApplication ADD NoOfDays AS (coalesce(DATEDIFF(day, StartDate, EndDate),0)+1) PERSISTED`, and you should have something that works.

Comment: @MattGibson Hi! I tried this but I got the error: Cannot execute CREATE COLUMN on/using table 'CurrentApplication' since the table is the target table or part of cascading actions of a currently executing trigger.

Comment: Are you trying to put the ALTER TABLE statement in a trigger? We're suggesting using a computed column *instead* of a trigger. Dropping your `NoOfDays` column and then running that single line of code, once, to re-create it as a computed column, should be everything you need. No triggers involved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2012 Insert DATEDIFF into column trigger whenever a new record is inserted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33428919/sql-server-2012-insert-datediff-into-column-trigger-whenever-a-new-record-is-ins)

Answer (score 1):

Totally normal.
Your update statement does not specify the "inserted" table.
Statement "from inserted" is missing. Therefore, "inserted" cannot be found.

Comment: Indeed. This is also a hint that you need to consider the case where multiple rows are inserted, so you may have more than one row in the `inserted` pseudo-table.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a trigger for this at all. A computed column would work fine for this case, and handle multiple-row inserts:

```
ALTER TABLE CurrentApplication DROP COLUMN NoOfDays;
ALTER TABLE 
    CurrentApplication 
    ADD NoOfDays AS (coalesce(DATEDIFF(day, StartDate, EndDate),0)+1) PERSISTED
```

This drops your existing `NoOfDays` column and then replaces it with a new [computed column](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx) that calculates `NoOfDays` whenever `StartDate` or `EndDate` changes and stores the calculated value alongside the other table data for speed.

Answer (score 0):

probably you are looking for a update join syntax; like

```
UPDATE c
SET NoOfDays = @temp
FROM CurrentApplication c
JOIN inserted i
ON c.HiddenID = i.HiddenId;
```

Comment: Hi! I tried this but I'm still getting the error invalid column name D:

Answer (score 0):

RMS is right, your trigger should look like this :

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertNoOfDays ON CurrentApplication
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE ca
    SET NoOfDays = (coalesce(DATEDIFF(day, i.StartDate, i.EndDate),0)+1) 
    FROM CurrentApplication ca
    INNER JOIN Inserted ON ca.HiddenID = i.HiddenId
END
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm still getting the same error D: